# Модальное окно, перекрывающее активность в остальной части окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделал модальное окно, но при его открытии возможна активность в остальной части экрана. Как сделать так, чтобы нельзя было клацать по другим объектам на странице, пока данной окно открыто?

Comment: вы можете дополнительно показывать враппер бекграундом, пока окно активно. Что не позволит клацать по части страницы

Answer (score 1):

Упрощенный пример. При выводе модального окна всю остальную часть сайта перекрываете полупрозрачным блоком. И вы уже не сможете кликнуть ни на кнопке ни на ссылке

```css
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 10;
}

.modal {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  left: 5rem;
  right: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Основной контент</h1>
<a href="#">Ссылка</a><br />
<button>Кнопка</button>
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="modal">Модальное окно</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

НА случай если вы пользуетесь jQ

```js
var wrap = $('#wrapper'),
     btn = $('.open-modal-btn'),
     modal = $('.cover, .modal, .content');

btn.on('click', function() {
  modal.fadeIn();
});

// close modal
$('.modal').click(function() {
  wrap.on('click', function(event) {
    var select = $('.content');
    if ($(event.target).closest(select).length)
      return;
    modal.fadeOut();
    wrap.unbind('click');
  });
});
```

```css
.cnt {
  text-align: center;
}

.cover {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 100;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  z-index: 300;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.open-modal-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="content">
      <p>THIS IS CONTENT</p>
      <form onsubmit="return false">
        <input type="text" placeholder="test">
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cnt">
    <button class="open-modal-btn">OPEN MODAL</button>
  </div>
</div>
```